# ifconfig - who decided that MAC address should be lowercase?

Tags: ifconfig

On some Linux computers, `ifconfig` displays the MAC address ("HWaddr") hex digits in uppercase.  On other Linux computers, the [a-f] digits are lowercase.

Why the difference?  Are there two competing versions of the program?  Is there an option somewhere to control it?

Comment: Beside ifconfig being obsolete, all relevant functions don't care if a hex digit is lower or upper case. What upsets you about lower case?

Comment: just curious as to why it's sometimes different.  Sure my tools can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting

Comment: Only see uppercase on my centos systems. Can you supply distro/version for the lowercase?

Comment: @ckhan which type of systems prefer uppercase?  My lowercase example was Ubuntu 12.04 (tested on desktop and server editions)

Comment: UC was centos, obviously. ignore previous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several possible reasons.

#### Different interface types

One possibility: `ifconfig` delegates printing of the hardware address to the interface implementation. Actual printing is performed by a function in the `interface` struct for the specific interface in `net-tools-1.60` (from [here](http://www.tazenda.demon.co.uk/phil/net-tools/)), called by `lib/interface.c`, line 678:

```
printf(_("HWaddr %s  "), hw->print(ptr->hwaddr));
```

See the source code for `nettools-1.60` in `lib/hw.c` for a list of supported interface types: There are separate implementations for ethernet, fiber, token ring, etc.

Now to the actual printing function: Example: `lib/ether.c`:

```
/* Display an Ethernet address in readable format. */
static char *pr_ether(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    static char buff[64];

    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
         (ptr[0] & 0377), (ptr[1] & 0377), (ptr[2] & 0377),
         (ptr[3] & 0377), (ptr[4] & 0377), (ptr[5] & 0377)
    );
    return (buff);
}
```

The different kinds of network interfaces can be implemented to display the same kind of information differently by using lowercase `x`s in the formatting string instead (i.e. `%02x` instead of `%02X`). For example, the IrDA interface uses lowercase hex digits (`lib/irda.c`):

```
/*
 * Function irda_print (ptr)
 *
 *    Print hardware address of interface
 *
 */
static char *irda_print(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    static char buff[8];

    sprintf(&buff[strlen(buff)], "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", ptr[3], ptr[2], 
        ptr[1], ptr[0]);

    return (buff);
}
```

#### Patches to `ifconfig`

Another possibility, and likely the reason here: Distributions often change the software packages. The above code snippet is from the original `net-tools-1.60`, let's look at Debian's, or rather, its patch `net-tools-1.60-23.diff` (from [here](http://packages.debian.org/source/stable/net-tools)):

```
+--- net-tools.orig/lib/ether.c
++++ net-tools/lib/ether.c
[...]
+@@ -39,7 +39,7 @@ static char *pr_ether(unsigned char *ptr
+ {
+     static char buff[64];
+ 
+-    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
++    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
+        (ptr[0] & 0377), (ptr[1] & 0377), (ptr[2] & 0377),
+        (ptr[3] & 0377), (ptr[4] & 0377), (ptr[5] & 0377)
+   );
```

So Debian patched the source code to `ifconfig` for their distribution, which might also get picked up by Ubuntu ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#History_and_development_process): "*Ubuntu packages are based on packages from Debian's unstable branch*").

Comment: Should both Cap and Lower work fine in HWADDR field?\